# Labelling NMDS plots in R

Tags: r, graphics, vegan

[enter image description here][1]
I am having an issue with metaMDS and ordiplot from the vegan package. I am new to this so I can't come up with an ultra flashy example.

Using ordiplot I would like to label plots according to a type (the groups A, B, C, D, E). I have a data frame "df" with a column of plot names and a column of the type. I NO LONGER care whether the type is illustrated by color or with different types of points. 
my very basic example:

```
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
dist.dune<-distShell(dune, distSimRatio)
ord<-metaMDS(dist.dune)
metaMDS(comm=dune)
plot(ord, type="n")
colfactor<-factor(dune.env$Management)
points(ord, display="sites", cex=2, pch=21, col=c(1,2,3,4,5)[colfactor])
text(ord, display="sites", cex=2, col=c(1,2,3,4,5)[colfactor])
```

UPDATE: Checked through a friends script and found a slightly different solution. This works on the dune data and is easily verfiable.
The same solution does NOT work on my data however. I can pretty easily check my NMDS results (the attribute I am trying to color by is part of my point names) and their coloring makes no sense, it is however correct in the sense that the correct amount of plots is colored in one color. It is also always the same points that are grouped into one color, seemingly by random.

UPDATE: warning message has disappeared. Now I only get the warning that the species scores are not available, which is clear, since I used a distance matrix for the calculation

UPDATE: [Look at the image below, the letter after the underscore is the plot type, same as the type I used in colfactor. Clearly the results are off :/][2]

UPDATE: [the last letter of the labels specifies the type like in my table, so strR should be where all the triangles are, since both of the labelling commands are identical][1]

Comment: Please can you make an reproducible example, perhaps use the `dune` dataset.

Comment: We really need more detail. I had no problem in running your example code with the `dune` data in **vegan**. I can only guess what could be wrong. Here some guesses: You have something wrong in your data (most likely in `df$type`)? Your `nmds` is not a `metaMDS` result object?

Comment: _I corrected the previous post to give a complete update_

Comment: If you use a factor as `col`, its internal numerical values are used as colours with the current `palette()`. Check what you get from `levels(colfactor)` or `as.numeric(colfactor)` and how that compares to the output of your `palette`.  If your variable is text, it should give colour in some form accepted by **R** (values of `colours()` or `colors()` or as RGB code).

Comment: ... and by *text* I mean **text**. Factors are not treated as text but they will be turned into numbers with internal ordering of levels. So `cf <- factor(c("red","green","blue"))` will be interpreted as `palette()[as.numeric(cf)]` which in my system makes `"green3" "red"    "black"`. Use `as.character(cf)` to use the textual value of a factor instead of its internal numeric value.

Comment: The question is not about choosing the right colors, but about the coloring being wrong and not corresponding to the factor that I specified it with. levels(colfactor) reveals my five chosen letters for the factor ACIRS

Comment: R is coloring my plots according to a factor, it is however doing so in a very specific incorrect way: The amounts of plots colored say in green corresponds with the **amount** of plots I would like to be colored in green, however the color differences do not reflect the type I specified. It is as if my table were off (e.g. the wrong type in the type column), which it is not. I structured my plot names to include the type as last letter, so it really can't be.

Comment: If the colours are off, your factor is off: fix it! You may start by checking the alignment: check the match of the labels and levels of factors. Alternatively, you may leak out some information about your data. We are blindly guessing, since there is nothing we can reproduce. Obviously you have coded your data wrongly, but we cannot see it here (and it is your task to straighten up your data).

Comment: Thanks and sorry. I joined here to learn more, since R and statistics are generally poorly taught and I needed somewhere to go with questions.

Comment: **misalignment** : there was a minor mismatch of sorts. The species table was not sorted by the same variable as the environmental table, leading to the plotting vector from one not corresponding to the other in the same levels. type "colfactor" and you will see all yout get is a string of factors with no connection to the original table itself.

Comment: This misalignment being ultimately my fault I apologize. However the problem is still persisting now with the fitting of the environmental values and the drawing of hulls 'orditorp' and 'ordihull'.